# Smart URL with optional parameters?

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, url

I currently have this in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(\w+)(/(\w+))?/?$ route.php?1=$1&2=$3 [L]
```

So I can do `myurl.com/foo/bar(/)` or just `myurl.com/foo(/)` (optional trailing slash, can't lose)

I'm not very familiar with regular expression, so how would I have this allow up to around 6 parameters `(myurl.com/one/two/three/four/five/six)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)(?:/(\w+))?(?:/(\w+))?(?:/(\w+))?(?:/(\w+))?(?:/(\w+))?/?$ route.php?1=$1&2=$2&3=$3&4=$4&5=$5&6=$6 [L]
```

You can check it [here](http://regex101.com/r/oM3nK8)

---

To allow spaces in the parameters you can use:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w\ ]+)(?:/([\w\ ]+))?(?:/([\w\ ]+))?(?:/([\w\ ]+))?(?:/([\w\ ]+))?(?:/([\w\ ]+))?/?$ route.php?1=$1&2=$2&3=$3&4=$4&5=$5&6=$6 [L]
```

Comment: It works, but now spaces don't work in the parameters. That's very bad.

Comment: You mean `myurl.com/one/two and a half/three`??

Comment: Yes. It just goes to the 404 page and not route.php.

Comment: replace every `\w+` with `[\w ]+`

Comment: "500 Internal Server Error" when I replace like you said.

Comment: Here is the new line: RewriteRule ^([\w +])(?:/([\w +]))?(?:/([\w +]))?(?:/([\w +]))?(?:/([\w +]))?(?:/([\w +]))?/?$ route.php?1=$1&2=$2&3=$3&4=$4&5=$5&6=$6 [L]

Comment: Internal server error can be many things... Look at the logs for the actual error...

Comment: .htaccess: RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters

Comment: It's still not working. Does anyone else have any input?

Comment: @Zapk - your pattern is full of `[\w +]` instead of `[\w ]+`

Comment: Sorry, the one I copy/pasted was the one I tried using `[\w +]` instead of `[\w ]+`. I was able to fix it by using `[\w\ ]+`.