# There is a better and smart solution for multiple parameters in .htaccess?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

im trying to build an .htaccess better and smarter, using this code http://regex101.com/r/oM3nK8/2
re-edited solution that i found here [Smart URL with optional parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23161263/smart-url-with-optional-parameters#23161434) on link that he mention.
Worked pretty well that way.

So, i changed to match characters in sequence.
If parameter 3 is not number, all the others parameters in sequence, must not shown (i.e. param 4, param 5, etc).

Is there a solution smart for one line, instead of multiple lines like this (only example):

```
RewriteRule ^urlDefault/([a-z]+)$ urlDefault.php?param1=$1
RewriteRule ^urlDefault/([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)$ urlDefault.php?param1=$1&param2=$2
RewriteRule ^urlDefault/([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-z]+)$ urlDefault.php?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3
```

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/oM3nK8/3

Comment: @hjpotter92 Thank you! For sure im write something wrong....